# Centering an image next to an image

Tags: html, css

I want to center an image next to an image as shown here:

[image]

My current code is:

css

```
.slider-btns img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto; 
}
```

html

```
<div class="slider-btns">
  <img src="assets/img/arrow-left.png" style="width:50px" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
  <img src="assets/img/arrow-right.png" style="width:50px" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
</div>
```

Comment: Remove `display: block;` from the images, add `text-align: center` to the container instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `img` elements are `inline` by default, you could just use `text-align: center` to center them horizontally.

```
.slider-btns {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Just remove the other styling and it will work as expected. The `img` elements can't be `block` level because they won't respect the `text-align` property..

```
.slider-btns img { /* Remove these */
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: @MrE It does here - http://jsfiddle.net/yupxgmg0/ .. perhaps there is some conflicting CSS.